# Inserting to database which is synchronised with another DB

Tags: sql

I have a staging database which is synchronised to production DB every 10 minutes. Also while testing in staging environment, data is inserted in to staging database. My issue is like if there are 100 records in production and staging and a user starts testing in staging and 101th record is inserted to a table in staging. After sometime, a new record is inserted to production and the same is syncronised to staging in 10 min. At this time, the script is trying to insert the new record with id 101 from production to staging database, but the same id is already there.

Has anyone faced this issue before ? Any idea or tools to resolve this issue ? Please help me.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Postgresql to MS SQL Server... Those aren't really compatible.

Comment: My mistake; both are postgres SQL. Deleting my old comment to avoid confusion